# Multiple LED at different time

Tags: python, led

I am trying to turn on three different LED but I want them to turn off at different time but this look impossible....  :cry: 
Here is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
import time from threading 
import Thread 
def led1(): 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) 
GPIO.setup(36, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.output(36,1) 
time.sleep(3) 
GPIO.output(36,0) 
GPIO.setwarnings(False) 
def led2(): GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) 
GPIO.setup(38, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.output(38,1) 
time.sleep(5) 
GPIO.output(38,0) 
GPIO.setwarnings(False) 
def led3(): 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) 
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.OUT) 
GPIO.output(40,1) 
time.sleep(7) 
GPIO.output(40,0) 
GPIO.setwarnings(False) 
thread1= Thread(target = led1) 
thread2= Thread(target = led2)
thread3= Thread(target = led3) 
thread1.run() thread2.run() 
thread3.run() 
##thread1.join () // not sure if I have to put that or not 
##thread2.join() 
##thread3.join() 
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(36, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(38, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.output(36,1)
GPIO.output(38,1)
GPIO.output(40,1)

time.sleep(3)
GPIO.output(36,0)
time.sleep(2)
GPIO.output(38,0)
time.sleep(2)
GPIO.output(40,0)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Edit: If you don't know the times each led will be on for:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(36, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(38, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(40, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

led1time = 3
led2time = 5
led3time = 7
m = max(led1time, led2time, led3time)

GPIO.output(36,1)
GPIO.output(38,1)
GPIO.output(40,1)

t = 0
while t <= m:
    if t >= led1time:
        GPIO.output(36,0)
    if t >= led2time:
        GPIO.output(38,0)
    if t >= led3time:
        GPIO.output(40,0)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    t += 0.1

GPIO.cleanup()
```

You can now set how long each led will be on for with 0.1 seconds accuracy, and you can increase that accuracy by replacing any occurrences of 0.1 with a lower number.

Comment: The problem with that is that the second one need to wait 2+3 second before being off and the third one will nee 3+2+2 seconds and the next stage of the code was to ask the user to input the time so if t2 is lower than t1 it will not work

Comment: I have updated my answer, in the future this information should be included in the question.